# Changing the offset and span on an analog voltmeter

Tags: voltage, analog, dc, meter

I have an analog meter. It belongs on an electric e-bike..

The default reading is about 88v-84v DC high side and 63v DC low side.

It has a resistor and diode on one side then two diodes in series on the other side.

I was wondering if I could change this meter to read 140v-130v DC high side than about 88-84v DC on the low side.

I have included some pictures of the project in question.

(Resistor) Green, Brown, Brown (Diode) ST 1N4748a

(Diode) ST 1N4747A then ST 1N4746A in series

(Coil) 0.812 - 0.808 k ohm

Any idea how/what I could use to measure the desired targeted voltage?

Or some math formula for dummies that could be followed for other voltages to determine the best formula for this type of alteration.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why such a large range? to include charger voltage? what kind of meter? 50uA?

Comment: can you measure meter coil resistance?

Comment: 0.812, 132v charged. 125v float, 83-80v is discharged.

Comment: Changing the voltage range should be doable. But you **must** include the schematic of the current circuit so that we can do some calculations and see what needs to be changed. Also look up the resistor values on a website that translates the color rings for you. Describing it in text is simply not good enough. I also doubt that this is the **complete** circuit, you have to include everything which is connected between the meter and the battery.

Comment: The positive and negative terminal leads are 22 gauge wire. It is attached to the wiring harness. Everything attached to this point is split into many other aspects such as the breaker,  right to access power (key) then dc converter. I can look up the part numbers and include it in the original post. However... creating a schematic is beyond my skill level for this question.

Comment: We're not looking for a schematic of the bike - just the meter. Tony asked you for the coil resistance. Can you measure it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fAzUyY.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. The meter wiring based on OP's first photo and text.*

How it works:

- D1, D2 and D3 are Zener diodes. With the three in series as shown no current will flow through the meter coil until the voltage rises to more than 22 + 20 + 18 = 60 V.
- Above this voltage the meter will swing progressively towards full scale.
- From your readings it appears that the meter goes from zero to full scale with an additional 20 V.

Your modified meter specification is as follows:

- Voltage span: 84 - 134 V DC.

To achieve this we need to do two things:

1. Add another Zener in series to raise the start voltage. You need an 80 - 60 = 24 V Zener.
2. Add some further series resistance.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fxtClL.png)</sup>

*Figure 2. Modified meter circuit.*

When you provide the meter coil resistance as requested in comment #2 we can calculate that.

---

The coil appears to be 812 Ω. So we get full scale deflection with a total resistance of 510 + 812 = 1324 Ω at 20 V.

- To change this to full scale deflection of 50 V (134 - 84) we need the total resistance to be \$ R_{TOT} = 1324 \cdot \frac {50}{20} = 3310 \; \Omega \$.
- R2, therefore, should be 3310 - 1324 = 1986 Ω or 2 kΩ.

Comment: I used the ohm setting on the meter and it gave 0.812 from one terminal to the other with no resistors or diodes attached to the terminal posts.

Comment: 0.812 what? You need to specify the units when you take measurements. I'm going to assume kΩ which means it is 812 Ω.

Comment: Yes. the K ohm symbol  https://i.imgur.com/GJQUvwF.jpg

Comment: OK. See the update. Note that your meter is correctly showing a small 'k' for "kilo". 'K' is "kelvin" for temperature measurement. Capitals matter!

Answer (score 0):

First problem is trying to guess a schematic from incomplete information like meter current full scale.

1N4746/7/8 = 16/18/20V ratings (from datasheet)

> string 1 = R=510 ohms + 20V
>
> string 2 = 16V + 18V = 34V
>
> both strings = 54 V + I*R with R = 510 + meter DCR

- Assuming your info is correct what deflection % of full-scale at min voltage =86 V  now IR= 9 V the difference from your reading of 63V and Zener string of 54 V
- assuming 100% full-scale = 88V , then IR= 34 V. The unknown here is coil resistance Rs, as the added 510 ohms would result in excessive current without the meter, Rs which extends the voltage range.
- to change from 88-63= 25V to 140-84 = 64 V the offset by adding zeners is 84-63= 21 V and the gain change by adding unknown R is 64/25V or 2.56 implies approx . something less than 2.56* 510 ohms or 1.3k depending on Rs of the coil.

> So my initial estimate depending on your Rs meter measurement is add 1N4748 (22V) with correct orientation,  and add R= 1300-510= 790 ohm or less.

Although it is not  that super, this is just a SWAG.